# CSS - How to create dropdown navigation bar with dynamic width of submenu

Tags: php, html, css

A lot of people have tried to make a navigation bar, but in most cases the width of the sub-menus is static, like [this example](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

What I'm trying to do is to make the width dynamic.
In my case, the name of the sub-menus will come from MySQL, so all the sub-menus will be determined dynamically.

For instance, if there are 3 sub-menus and the longest one has 3 characters, the width of the sub-menus will be 3 characters-long. However, if there comes another menu which has 6 characters, I'd like to have the width of all the sub-menus twice wider than that.

I thought this can be done by having the `width` property `100%`, it didn't work as expected.

Here are some pieces of my coding.

```css
#menu {}
/*1st level*/

#menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
/*1st level items*/

#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
/*2nd level list*/

#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
/*2nd items*/

#menu ul li ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/*3rd level list*/

#menu ul ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
/*3rd level items*/

#menu ul li ul li ul li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
/*When the 1st level items are hovered, the 2nd livel list is shown*/

#menu ul li:hover >ul {
  display: block;
}
/*Hovered itemes will be in a different collor*/

#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #00FFCC;
}
/*When the 2nd level items are hovered, the 3rd livel list is shown*/

#menu ul li ul li:hover >ul li {
  display: block;
}
/*This is what happens when items are hovered*/

#menu li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <!-- 1st level menu-->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Patterns</a>
      <!-- 2nd level menu-->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Event</a>
          <!-- 3rd level menu-->
          <ul>
            <?php while ($data=m ysqli_fetch_array($result_event)) { if($data[ 'Category']=="Event" ){ ?>
            <li>
              <a href="pattern.php?PatternName=<?php echo $data['PatternName']; ?>">
                <?php echo $data[ 'PatternName']; ?>
              </a>
            </li>
            <?php } } ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The following picture is how the navigation bar works.

[image]

The bottom line "Form-based Event Capture" is the longest in the 3rd level menus, so the width of all the menu in the same level should be the as this line.

I'd appreciate if you would give any insight.

PS

You might notice that `left` property of the 3rd `ul` is 70%. If it's 100%, there will be a gap between the 2nd `ul` and the 3rd `ul`.
I'm wondering if any of you see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Currently your code snippet does not output what is shown in the image. Please try to replicate it for us to debug.

Comment: your 1st level selector `#menu ul`actually applies to all `ul` elements under `#menu` the direct descendant operator `>` should be used to select immediate children only `#menu > ul`

Comment: > Manoj - Thanks for your comment. I edited it.

Comment: >andrew - Thank you for your suggestion. Did you mean that I need to use `>` for the 3rd level list `#menu ul ul ul` ? I'm afraid I don't think it works. This is because when I change the `background-color` of `#menu ul ul ul`, the back ground color of this level changes to the expected color. So, I honestly don't think the 1st level selector `#menu ul` applies to all `ul`. (I mean, `#menu ul` doesn't affect the 2nd & 3rd level)